# How to correct this formula with If function?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a data filled from Column C9 to column I39
AND I Auto-Add text in Column J using this formula:
`=ArrayFormula(IF(I9:I39="Excellent","Excellent",IF(I9:I39="Good","Good",IF(I9:I39="Bad","Bad",""))))`

I want to add also `If(AND(C9:C39<>"",I9:I39=""),"Not Filled","")`
But I couldn't add it the the previous line.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wRckJYig3zh2hon2xgCFpz_VeWHu8ky_uwVm4dhmH1A/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, you want to use an `Arrayformula` while using the `AND( , )` function. It won't work, you should use this instead:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(If((C9:C39<>"")*(I9:I39=""),"Not Filled",""))
```

**Note:**

Within `ARRAYFORMULA`:

- to use `AND`, we use *
- To use `OR`, we use +

Your first formula could also be simplified as follows:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(I9:I),I9:I,""))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

```
=IFERROR(SWITCH(I9:I39,"Bad","Bad","","Not Filled","Excellent","Excellent"))
```

You can also take it a step further

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C9:C="",,IFERROR(SWITCH(I9:I,"Bad","Bad","","Not Filled","Excellent","Excellent"))))
```

**Functions used:**

- [`ARRAYFORMULA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`SWITCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013690)

Comment: Using `IF` is an overkill.

Comment: Great Commentators. Thanks

Comment: Switch is really great function. Thanks